# Не работает col-md

Tags: bootstrap

Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу разобраться. Блок с контактами отображается на col-lg, пропадает на col-md и снова появляется на col-sm. Что я делаю не так?
На col-md нужно такое же поведение дива как и на col-sm.

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
}

.btn-info {
    width:156px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light" style="background-color: #fff;">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="https://3д-блок.рф/i/yellow-logo/125/125/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%202.jpg.jpg"/></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample11">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarsExample11">
            <ul class="navbar-nav text-center options" id="navbarsExample12">
                <li class="nav-item py-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info rounded-0">Узнать цену</button>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item py-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info rounded-0 ml-1">Калькулятор</button>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item py-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info rounded-0 ml-1">Заказать</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 justify-content-center col-md-12 justify-content-center col-lg-3 justify-content-end">
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column text-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">+375 (29) 123-88-77</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">company@gmail.com</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
    </div>
    
</nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего не куда не проподает у вас проста из за того что не правильно сетка распределяетсья появляетсья горизонтальный скролл и контакты по правой части сетки странице скрываютсья надо было проста поскроллить на право чтобы увидеть проблему.

Также я чуть изменил вашу сетку чтобы вы увидели блок контакты думаю полностью сами доделаете.

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.btn-info {
    width:156px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light" style="background-color: #fff;">
<a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="https://3д-блок.рф/i/yellow-logo/125/125/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%202.jpg.jpg"/></a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample11">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarsExample11">
        <ul class="navbar-nav text-center options" id="navbarsExample12">
            <li class="nav-item py-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info rounded-0">Узнать цену</button>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item py-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info rounded-0 ml-1">Калькулятор</button>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item py-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info rounded-0 ml-1">Заказать</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12   col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 justify-content-center justify-content-center  justify-content-end">
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column text-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">+375 (29) 123-88-77</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">company@gmail.com</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>

</nav>
    </div>
</header>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```